# iPhone App for restricted set of users?

Tags: ios, ios5, appstore-approval

Is it possible to create an iPhone App for certain group of users ? Like, can we create some kind of private group on App Store and our clients could go to that group and then the app would be available to them ?

If my app has a start-up page like asking for License/Pin , so could only those users access it who have that Pin , would it be acceptable for App Store ?

Basically I want to set access of my app to limited set of users, so what are my options here ? I dont want to go to 'Enterprise Program' as my users are not employees of my organization they could be any one , any where in the world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the application should be available for everyone, otherwise it will not be accepted for publishing on Appstore. However it is allowed to require some kind of registration, whether is for free or does cost something. It is also possible for a software to require some kind of hardware as well. For example an application that works as a remote control for a media player.

There is no such thing as a group on Appstore.

Comment: So if I add login page in start of my App , then would it be acceptable ? As my App is not general purpose app , it is designed for specific audience...so that's why I need login page credentails/Pin to enter in start of a app to load.

Comment: One criteria is that you provide the Apple reviewers with account details, so that they will be able to log in to the service that you are providing. This could be some kind of demo account. There are numerous applications that starts with a login page.

Comment: So my _guess_ is that it will be acceptable. However you will never know until you have tried to push through your application to the appstore.

Comment: You could take a look at [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041118/hidden-features-in-iphone-app) as well.

Comment: ok thanks Johan. So I guess I will make 2,3 general info pages and for the proper app functionality there will be login page, which will let the users to enter in and use the functionality of app.

Answer (score 0):

You could register as an Enterprise. Ther is an iOS Enterprise Deployment Guide [Link](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/Enterprise_Deployment_Guide.pdf)

As I know you can manage your enterprise devices there and also distribute Apps to your devices without the need to use the AppStore. You need an enterprise distribution profile to sign the app and then users can install your enterprise app via iTunes.

Comment: Additional you can find information here https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following post might solve your issue:
http://www.foraker.com/ios-app-distribution-options/

In short, Apple allows you to create B2B applications, where only the selected companies can use the created applications:
https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/